# Можно ли создать абсолютный элемент отностельно img?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли каким-либо образом создать абсолютный элемент по отношению к img?

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода. Сложно понять что именно вы имете ввиду.

Comment: Ну допустим у нас есть элемент img, и элемент h3, можно ли сделать так что бы элемент h3 позиционировался абсолютно по отношению к img?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно относительные элементы собирают в контейнер и там их позиционируют.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<img src="ссылканамаюкартингу">
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"><h3>Заголовок</h3></div></div>
```